# Updating a Visual Studio project made from an imported WSP file?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, import

I have a project in Visual Studio 2010 that was created by importing a WSP file. This file was generated by saving a site as a template.

Now the original site has changed (new list definitions and instances, new site columns etc.). Is there some way to update the Visual Studio Project so that it will contain all the new definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direclty, but only by importing the definitions of each artifact used, or save again the site as template and import solution via Visual Studio, than adapt.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve your problem can Beyond Coparer tool. This is very useful tool to merge texts, folders, files etc.

You can find this following [this](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) link.

This is payed tools but you can use tral version to achive your goal

Hope it helps,

Andrew